# AWS loopback approach and mounting an EBS Volume

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

In order to deploy your appliance on AWS, I think the [loopback approach](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-loopback-s3-linux.html) is true IaaS and I am not in favor of installing my software on an existing AMI. I see a potential problem of using loopback when you want to put your database(RDBMS) on an EBS drive. In the loopback approach when you are creating your image on your local system, you may already install the database in whatever location before your image gets uploaded to EC2. If I want to use EBS to store my database the only option I can think of right now is to defer installation of schema to first boot on EC2 followed by attaching an EBS drive. Any other ideas how you would take care of this?

Answer (score 1):

Q: Do you suggest loopback meaning for an encrypted volume?

At instance creation, you can specify an EBS Volume to mount for your database to store data.

Your startup scripts will need to look for this and either move the existing data directory or rebuild it from scratch.

I do this pretty regularly using MySQL with their datadir on an EBS volume.